# Keep unique lines only, searching entire directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

**BACKGROUND INFORMATION**

Working on my router, so only 60mb free ram.
I welcome answers in `bash`, but `sh` would make my day.
If there is a binary that does this, i don't mind compiling it to run on my router.

**TL;DR**

I have a directory with text files.

How can i make sure that, between all files, i do not have repeated lines?

For example, if `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt` contains the line `apple`, it should remain only in one of them (doesn't matter which one).

**IF YOU WANT DETAILS**

I have a script downloading multiple `hosts` files in the same directory, used by dnsmasq.

I do not want to merge all files into one, but keep them all deleting the repeated hostnames.

For example, in

```
y.txt

127.0.0.1    google.com
127.0.0.1    yahoo.com
```

and

```
z.txt

0.0.0.0    apple.com
0.0.0.0    yahoo.com
```

the line containing the domain `yahoo.com` should be deleted from one of them.

if this line also exists in another file, should be deleted from it as well.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

1- concatenating all files into one, sorting and keeping only unique lines.
having only one big file is not the ideal solution here.

2- iterating over the files, comparing each one with the remaining.
saving the result in a temporary file, sorting, removing duplicated lines and finally renaming the temp file to replace the original.
seems like i'm wasting resources here.

Comment: You need two passes through all your files.  In the first pass, build an associative array (hash) with domain as the key and filename as the value. Store the domain only once in the hash so that duplicates are ignored.  In the second pass, read the domain from the file, and lookup the hash to see if the file name in hash matches the current file.  If so, retain the domain, otherwise, delete it.

Comment: You could also use a file (say, all_domains.txt) instead of a hash wherein you store domain and filename.  In the second pass, you could do a `grep domain all_domains.txt | head -1` to see which file the domain belongs to.  If it belongs to something other than the current file being processed, you could remove that domain from the file.

Comment: @codeforester nice! really liked your ideas. unfortunately i cant go with the array because i'm working on my router (only 60mb free ram). and about the `all_domains` file, it kind of defeat the purpose of having several small files, since `dnsmasq` can read from the big `all_domains` file.

Comment: I suggested that solution because you didn't want to merge all your small files.

Comment: @codeforester i know. it just feels like a waste of resources merging all files into a big one that will not be used, or will just be split again in small files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you are attempting to do fairly easily using `sed` and a temporary file. Simply copy one of the file (e.g `z.txt`) to a temp file. Then read each line in the other file (e.g. `y.txt`) and separate into `ip` and `host`. Then call `sed -i` to edit the temp file in place deleting any line with a matching `$host` name. When you are done, replace `z.txt` with the temp file.

For example:

```
cp -a z.txt z.tmp                   ## copy z.txt to temp file
while read -r ip host; do           ## read each line in y.txt
    sed -i "/.*$host/d" z.tmp       ## delete $host from temp
done < y.txt
mv -f z.tmp z.txt                   ## replace z.txt with temp
```

When you are done:

```
$ cat z.txt
0.0.0.0    apple.com
```

There are probably several other ways to accomplish the same thing with `awk` or simply `grep`, but grep would require a read of both files.

Comment: so, if i have 4 files, how could i iterate each one comparing with the remaining only once?

Comment: Instead of running `sed` against `z.tmp` alone, you would create `tmp` files for all `3` other files (e.g. `w.tmp`, `x.tmp` and `z.tmp`), then simply `sed -i "/.*$host/d" *.tmp`. That will delete any host found in `y.txt` from any of the `tmp` files. Then just move all 3 `tmp` files back to the `.txt` files when done.

Comment: So if you have 4 files, you can iterate one and delete from the other 3 all in one pass. You would have to do a round-robin and iterate over all 4 (one and then three others -- for each file) to insure you eliminate all dupes.

Answer (score 2):

can you try this awk. it will not replace in the file. it just take the unique records of 2nd column from all files

```
awk '!A[$NF]++' *.txt
```

Comment: I thinks that's a very elegant solution, but the OP points out in a comment that keeping all files in memory is beyond the 60 MB they have at their disposal.

Comment: very nice! if i ever decide to go with the 'one big file' method, will certainly use this! can `awk` also output the sorted result? or i have to pipe it to `sort`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. – I would assume 60M would be enough; this only stores the unique hostnames, so there's no storage of IPs or duplicates. I'm not sure dnsmasq can handle that many entries without having caching issues of its own.

Comment: @RASG – This will be sorted by the first occurrence of each host.  To do better than that, you'd have to pipe it through `sort -k2` or so.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
!p[$0]++
```

Or:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '!p[$0]++' *.txt
```